# What are these little holes for on the underside of the very back of my car?

Tags: toyota, corolla, towing

Can this be used to pull a 100lb wagon on private property or would that damage the car because the holes are for another purpose?

[image]

Comment: What is the year/make/model of the vehicle?

Comment: Have you looked in the owners manual to see if it says what they are for?

Comment: Are those two holes on a bracket intended to be used to mount a tow-ball hitch? If they are and you fix something else directly, there is a possibility that the metal gets distorted enough so that you can't fit the tow hitch later. I suggest you fit a proper tow and not improvise. For occasional towing there often are accessible (but not always obvious) towing eyes front and/or back.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It's a 2017 Toyota Corolla

Comment: Google is useful when using key words. One example of the correct tow hitch;   https://youtu.be/lgQx6IxUhCw. The tow bar is horizontally mounted onto left and right side of the rear chassis for proper towing.

Answer (score 1):

The [towing capacity](https://towingcap.com/toyota/corolla/2017/) for your Corolla should be 1500lbs. The car itself should be able to tow the 100lb trailer plus cargo without too much of an issue. The problem lies in where you are wanting to connect the trailer at. *Could you connect it there and tow successfully?* Sure. Probably 99 out of a 100 times you'd be just fine. The problem is, it's not really a good idea to just find a hole and use it. As Weather Vane stated in comments, you run a really good chance of distorting the metal there because it probably isn't meant to be used as a towing base.

Bottom line here is, get a proper hitch installed. You won't regret it.